# Xib inside xib with auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I have a custom `UIView` class with xib added inside another xib by overriding    `awakeAfterUsingCoder:`.

In the parent xib, I have a height constraint for the child xib and when I set this constraint to 0, the subviews of the child xib are not updated (even if the child xib height is set to 0). Need some guidance on why this is not affecting the child xib. What could be the problem in this case ?